# How can I insert XML example code inside a Joomla article?

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I'm building a site in Joomla 2.5 that covers topics related to programming.

I have tried various plugins and I had no problem to insert java, javascript and php code inside my articles (the classic view with indented line number)

The problem arises when I try to insert XML.

Currently I'm using the plugin Code HighLight (but I found the same thing with other plugins).

To insert the XML code in my article I have to do so in my article:

```
{code class="brush: xml;"}CODE HERE{/code}
```

The problem is that, if I insert Java or Js or php code I have no problem, but if I try to insert XML code in this way in my article it appears bad (parts missing)

I also tried to plug it directly into HTML (by pressing the button HTML editor TinyMCE) but, once inserted, when I come back to the WYSIWING editor, this problem occurs again.

In the plugin instruction I can read:

**BEWARE of your visual editor (JCE or JCK for example), it can place tags in your code, after this code became invalid!**

I use TinyMCE as editor (it is always a WYSIWYG editor) and seems that this is the problem infact if I disable the graphical editor (inside the Joomla global configuration setting the editor as void) or if I choose the CodeMirror editor (that it is a simple HTML editor, not a WYSIWING editor) if I insert the XML code in te previus way...work well !!!

The problem is that I need a graphical editor (to set the styile of my articles text) and at the same time I need to insert XML code snippet inside my articles...

I have observed that behavior using many code snippet plugin...the problem is not a plugin problem but I think it is related to the WYSIWING editor that seems to insert it's tag inside the XML code or at least makes it dirty (eliminates parts and inserts some tags like

)

What can I do to have XML code snippet in my articles and at the same time have a WYSIWING editor? (if the problem is TinyMCE I can also try some other WYSIWING editor...)

Thanks
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

You can give extension for [code display](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/code-display) a try.

Another solution I read about was
1) activate Content - Code Highlighter (GeSHi)
2) generate your code [here](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/demo.php)
3) C&P the generated code in the WYSIWYG editor

Answer (score 0):

You can do either one or the other...you cannot do both.
My suggestion is this:  do the WYSIWYG part of the page...toggle the WYSIWYG editor off...then insert your xml...and NEVER go back to that page with the WYSIWYG editor on again.

I have had the same issues inserting xml in my website.

If you have logged out of joomla and log back in...the default is the WYSIWYG editor.

So if you open an article/module/plugin and it opens in WYSIWYG, it clears the xml that you have inserted into the page.  Simply toggle the WYSIWYG editor so that it is off...then CLOSE the article (DO NOT SAVE & CLOSE)...just close.  Then open the article/module/plugin again...it should be the html editor only...and code away.

I hope this helps.